Where can I find a novel in modern Mandarin which I can read aloud on YouTube in full?
I practice Chinese on YouTube.  For this goal, I'd like to make a YouTube video where I read aloud the entirety of a Chinese novel.  So I'm looking for a novel which:

is in modern Mandarin (the last 50 or so years; books from 100 years ago are too hard) and
has a copyright which permits me to read the entire novel on YouTube.

Ideally the novel will not contain adult themes and swear words.  Digital and physical novels are both okay.  I'm guessing there'll be some kind of Creative Commons web novel out there I can use.
Question: Where can I find a novel in modern Mandarin which I can read aloud on YouTube in full?
